# Variable Y-Axis That Adjusts to the Height of the columns

Tags: python, matplotlib, yaxis

I am looking to find a quick code for the y-axis limit currently set as follows

```
# Set the Y Axis Limits
ax.set_ylim(0,100)
```

I am looking to exchange the 100 for a variable/adjustable y level based on our data points, seen below:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

s = pd.Series(
[8, 24, 21, 23, 24],
index = ["Your Plan", "Benchmark", "Region", "Industry", "Size"]
)
```

Should be a quick fix, I'd imagine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set y axis limits by minimum and maximum values of your data series which are the results of numpy.max and numpy.min:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

s = pd.Series(
[8, 24, 21, 23, 24],
index = ["Your Plan", "Benchmark", "Region", "Industry", "Size"]
)

plt.plot(s.values)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_ylim(np.min(s),np.max(s))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can auto scale your axes if you add to code `plt.gca().autoscale_view()`. it allows to automatically adjust current axis limits to fit data.

Answer (score 0):

If you delete or not use the line `ax.set_ylim(0,100)`, the limits will automatically adjust to the data.

If you want to fix one end of the axis but let the other automatically adjust, you can also use

```
ax.set_ylim(0,None)
```